# How to assign values on multiple columns of a pandas data frame based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dtaframe df as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
  'A': [20,30,40,-50,60,-70 ], 
  'B': [21, -19, 20, 18, 17, -21], 
  'C': [1,12,-13,14,15,16], 
  'D': [-88, 92, 9, 70, -6, 78]})
```

I want every value on column ['C','D'] to be zero where the value is between -10 and 10, rest of the values should remain same.

is there something similar to `data.series.between`, which can be applied to a data frame
`df[(df[['C','D']].between(-10,10,inclusive=True)]=0`

output should be :

```
    A   B   C   D
0  20  21   0 -88
1  30 -19  12  92
2  40  20 -13   0
3 -50  18  14  70
4  60  17  15   0
5 -70 -21  16  78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) here after comparing by [`df.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) and [`df.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html):

```
df[['C','D']]=df[['C','D']].mask(df[['C','D']].ge(-10)&df[['C','D']].le(10),0)
```

Or [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df[['C','D']]=np.where(df[['C','D']].ge(-10)&df[['C','D']].le(10),0,df[['C','D']])
```

---

```
    A   B   C   D
0  20  21   0 -88
1  30 -19  12  92
2  40  20 -13   0
3 -50  18  14  70
4  60  17  15   0
5 -70 -21  16  78
```

Comment: can you please explain `ge(-10`) and `le(10)`

Comment: @Shijith it means greater than equal to -10 and less than equal to 10, click on the link on the answer to read more. :)

Comment: thank you, got it.  i thought those were only for pandas.series